# Delphi application retrieves incorrect date format on windows 10 system

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a delphi application compiled in delphi 10.2.2.
My task is to retrieve the system date format from delphi application.
I use following procedure

```
procedure TForm1.GetsSytemDateFormat;
var
  myDate : string;
begin
  myDate:=GetLocaleStr(GetThreadLocale(), LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, '');
  edtSysDefault.Text := myDate;
end;
```

to retrieve the date format.

When I execute the exe on windows 10 system if the system date format is set to dd-MM-yyyy then,
in delphi application its retrieved as **M/d/yyyy.**
I am trying to get same date format in delphi application as per the system date format.
However,the same application works on other systems having windows 7 and windows 10.
Can anyone tell me, what could be the issue with this?

Comment: normally delphi will do this automatically for you. Check [TFormatsettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.Create).

Comment: @whosrdaddy I tried using TFormatSettings ,it dint work.

Comment: [Doc's](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/Intl/locale-sshortdate) say: *Locales can define multiple short date formats. To get all of the short date formats for this locale, use EnumDateFormats, EnumDateFormatsEx, or EnumDateFormatsExEx.*

Comment: What format is retrieved if you retrieve the short datetime format with `GetUserDefaultLCID`?

Comment: @LU RD after using GetUserDefaultLCID  following short date format is retrieved:  dd\MM\yyyy  whereas the system date format is dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: If my memory serves me corectly Windows 10 allows setting custom format settings for each application individually.